# Trigger Pull To Refresh

Tags: codenameone

Any code sample on how to trigger Pull To Refresh in codenameone will be appreciated. Adding pull to refresh is simple but I have a use case where I need pull to refresh automatically done after form's post show.

Comment: Have a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [InfiniteContainer](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_the_infinitecontainer) does that implicitly but if you want to use the pull to refresh directly. Since pull to refresh accepts a `Runnable` you can just call its `run()` method on show.